# Python: Call a method with a given list of arguments

Tags: python, function-call

I am unit-testing my software with PyUnit and find it unfortunate that the assertions provided by mock objects (e.g. *mock.assert_called_with*) don't seem to provide a way to set a message in case the assertion fails. That's why I want to use a wrapper like this:

```
def wrap_mock_msg(mock_method, *args, msg):
try:
    mock_method(<args here!>)
except AssertionError as e:
    raise AssertionError(e.args, msg)
```

It takes the assertion method of a given mock object as *mock_method*, the message to be displayed upon failure as *msg*, and a series of arguments to be passed to the *mock_method* as *args*.
I need it to be a variable *args* list, since *mock.assert_called_with(arg1, arg2, .., arg_n)* can also take any number of arguments, depending on the method I'm trying to mock.

Unfortunately, I can't just pass a list of arguments to the *mock_method*, since it will of course be taken as a single argument. Now, this leads me to the challenge of having to pass the list of arguments to the *mock_method* as if I had hard-typed it. For example:

```
args = ['an', 'example']
```

..should result in the following call:

```
mock_method('an', 'example')
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can unpack the items in the list using the `*` operator. You would need to pass in the arguments as a tuple this way. The code would look like this:

```
def wrap_mock_msg(mock_method, args, msg):
    try:
        mock_method(*args)
    except AssertionError as e:
        raise AssertionError(e.args, msg)
```

Comment: There is no need in `*` operator in function definition statement: `def wrap_mock_msg(mock_method, args, msg):`

Comment: You're correct. Then the arguments would need to be passed in through a list/tuple.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification on the * operator. I do not understand @mxmt's suggestion though.

If I define the wrapper as suggested, and give the args as a tuple, the function will simply give me a TypeError since positional arguments are missing and the tuple is only passed like a list.

Comment: What @mxmt was saying what you could pass in the arguments as a list or tuple. For example, if the arguments were 1, 2, 3, then you would call `wrap_mock_msg(mock_method, (1,2,3), some_message)`

Comment: Ah yes, I see my mistake. Of course, both tuples and lists can be unpacked by the *. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can call:

```
mock_method(*args)
```

Unpacking works either way using the `*` operator. The arguments taken in the wrapper are unpacked into a list, then that list is unpacked into the function.